# How to float 2 column content to the next page

Tags: html, css, printing, flexbox

I'm working on html for a brochure and later on a PDF will be generated from this html to be able to be printed out. My page must have 2 columns and contents floating into these 2 columns if there are more content than can be fitted in 2 columns it should continue the same layout in next page. Basically it's like Microsoft word 2 column page when the content is more than a page it continues to the next page which has 2 columns. How can I achieve that in html and CSS?

Below is what I've got by now. The problem is when I add more content my page will be divided into more columns. I always want it to be 2 columns.

[image: The Blue section is my page size the Orange section must float to the next page column]

```css
.page {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.column {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E0FFF4;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
  min-height: 60px;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: #CEBFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">1. some text</div>
    <div class="content">2. some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text,</div>
    <div class="content">3. some text</div>
    <div class="content">4. some text</div>
    <div class="content">5. some longer text, some longer text, some longer text, some longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer textsome longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer text,some longer text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you are using `div` to add more content better use `p` or `span` tag

Comment: what if you create multiple .page divs?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/NhS98/ ?

Comment: check this link http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Comment: Please note that I need my content float to the next column that's why I used flex. How does that work if I use Css column and/or span and p instead of div ?